# Getting XY screen coords from ArcScene 3D point using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, coordinates, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I already know how to convert screen point (X,Y in pixels) to 3D point:

```
ISceneGraph pSceneGraph = m_pSceneHookHelper.SceneGraph;
IPoint pPoint;
pSceneGraph.Locate(pSceneGraph.ActiveViewer, X, Y, esriScenePickMode.esriScenePickFastLocation, true, out pPoint, out pOwner, out pObject);
```

But how may I get X,Y screen point from 3D point?
I just use snapping to change 3D point coordinates, so I need to know new screen coordinates to use Locate function (because I need to find feature object).